# Which driver messes with media keys on Dell 9550?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, audio, drivers, keyboard

#### System info

Dell XPS 15 9550 with Windows 10 19043.

#### Problem

I made the mistake of unnecessarily updating drivers with the program `Snappy Driver Installer`. It changed about [30 drivers](https://pastebin.com/cjjZ58Aj). The problem is that the **media keys** — the keys on the function row, F1-F12 — no longer work properly. This shows itself in 4 ways:

1. using **volume keys** no longer shows a volume popup window.
2. using screen **brightness keys** no longer shows a brightness popup
   window.
3. the **brightness keys** change the brightness in large, discrete
   steps of 10% (before it was a smooth change). sometimes when pressing the **brightness keys** the right-click
   a popup menu appears.
4. pressing the **play/pause, next or previous buttons** no longer
   shows a media popup.

Some wrong driver causes the problem. Which one is it?

#### Attempted solutions

Already tried using Dell SupportAssist, Dell Update, Windows Update. Tried reinstalling HID, display, Realtek audio drivers.

Comment: If System Restore is enabled, use it to rollback to a restore point from before this happened.

Comment: I  [used]  ‘Snappy Driver Installer’.  ... Don't use these things. They are almost never better than the manufacturer's Driver Updater. If no restore point, you might have to reinstall Windows.

Comment: I tried to rollback to a restore point before these events, but it failed, after which that restore point disappeared. I agree that these programs should not be used.

Comment: Do you have a list of the changed drivers? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: Some more advice: Download the [XPS 15 (9550) Windows 10 Driver Pack](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/fr-fr/000122128/xps-15-9550-windows-10-driver-pack), then install all the drivers via `dism /Online /Add-Package /PackagePath:"C:\path\.cab"`. Reboot Windows, check if the media keys work, and run Windows Update to see if it has better drivers.

Comment: @harrymc the log file from the program says it installed [these drivers](https://pastebin.com/cjjZ58Aj).

Comment: @harrymc DISM gives the following error: `An error occurred trying to open - C:\Users\*\9550-WIN10-A14-TV5DD.CAB Error: 0x80070002 | Error: 2 | System cannot find the file specified.`

Comment: Why is there an asterisk in the path to the `.cab`?

Comment: The asterisk is the username.

Answer (score 1):

First, please don't ever use that kind of shitty software/driver updater, always use Windows/Manufacturers.

Try to use `System Restore`. If it is disabled or you don't have a valid restore point, try to uninstall `Snappy Driver Installer` from Control Panel/Programs and Features.

1. If you see anything weird or related to that shit as `drivers`, go
   ahead and remove all you can find installed on the same date.
2. Restart Windows, and let it load default Windows 10 drivers.
3. Then go [this](https://www.dell.com/support/home/es-ar/product-support/product/xps-15-9550-laptop/drivers).
4. Register/Login and download the proper drivers and tools for your
   device.

If that doesn't work, backup all your stuff, and reinstall with a clean Windows 10 using [Create Windows 10 installation Media downloaded from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) and using [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/en/) to create a Bootable Media (USB stick).

Comment: You got a +1 from me by the end of the first line ;)

Comment: There's no restore point. Snappy Driver is a portable program. Unfortunately your answer is too generic, what driver is the problem and should I download?

Answer (score 0):

From your list of drivers, I would guess that these are to blame:

```
26. Logicool HID Keyboard Power Key
27. Logitech HID-Compliant Keyboard
28. Logicool HID Keyboard Consumer Controls
29. Logicool HID-compliant Cordless Mouse
```

These are all Logitech drivers, so pertain to the keyboard and mouse.
You need to remove them from the computer.

- Run Device Manager
- Click on the View menu and turn on "Show Hidden Devices"
- Expand the node that represents the type of device to uninstall,
  perhaps "Human Interface Devices"
- Right-click the device entry for the device to uninstall and select Uninstall
- On the "Confirm Device Removal" dialog box, to also remove the
  driver package in addition to uninstalling the device,
  select "Delete the driver software for this device".
- Click OK.
- Repeat for other likely devices, keeping the mouse to the last.
- Reboot the computer - after this the keyboard and mouse might become
  unusable, and in that case press once the Power button to shutdown
  the computer.
- On the next boot Windows will install its own drivers.
- If the media keys are not yet functional, search for a driver on
  the Dell website.

Create a System Restore point before starting, for backup.

Comment: Deleting the Logitech-devices didn't solve the problem unfortunately. There's 27 HID-devices, should I try deleting them all?

Comment: Yes - try to delete all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the program [DroidCam](https://www.dev47apps.com/) made the brightness and media popups reappear. This program had 2 audio device drivers. Strange, because the problem clearly started after using the driver program and I didn't do anything with or related to DroidCam in the meantime.